# Preserve special characters in variables (use exact characters) in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to preserve special characters in my variables when setting them. I am trying to save file paths as variables. For example:

**prompt**

*user input*

---

**click and drag your file here**

*/Users/leetbacon/Desktop/My\ Stuff/time\ to\ fly\ \&\ soar.png*

**You chose　/Users/leetbacon/Desktop/My\ Stuff/time\ to\ fly\ \&\ soar.png**

---

---

Instead, whenever I input the file it always outputs like this (which I DON'T want):

**You chose　/Users/leetbacon/Desktop/My Stuff/time to fly & soar.png**

---

Any way to get it to store the variable how I would like it?

Here's the code I have right now:

```
echo 'click and drag your file here'
read -p " " FilepatH
echo 'You chose '"$FilepatH"
```

I would like for it to preserve ALL special characters. I'm just trying to write a script that can cover all possibilities of file names.

And I'm using OS X Yosemite

--Todd

Comment: I don't see the problem. The backslashes are not part of the file name; they escape the spaces to prevent them from being treated as word separators by the shell.

Comment: Yes, but I need them to be preserved. Later on in the script, it uses the specified file/folder to do certain tasks to it.

Comment: No, they do not need to be preserved, if you are quoting the parameter expansions correctly. Otherwise, your script is broken. `foo="file with spaces.txt"; mv "$foo" "some other name.txt"`

Comment: What if the file name contains a single or double quote in its name? Or a forward or back slash? That's why I just want it to output how I'd like it. Is this not possible in bash?

I thought, maybe have it where it automatically adds `'`s at the beginning and end of the variable when setting it, so it does set properly. In my case, I just want them preserved.

Comment: You only need to escape characters in literals created by the shell. Once the parameter contains the value, it is safe as long as you continue to escape the parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like for it to preserve ALL special characters.

Done. In the script you posted, all characters are preserved.

You can verify that they are really preserved by running:

```
ls "$FilepatH"
```

This will work only because all special characters are preserved. If they were not preserved it wouldn't work, the file would not be found.

However, you might want to clarify the intent with the output:

```
echo "You chose '$FilepatH'"
```

This will print:

> ```
> You chose '/Users/leetbacon/Desktop/My Stuff/time to fly & soar.png'
> ```

Comment: Well, both you and Gordon helped. So, since I feel that both of you should deserve the accepted answer, I will just leave it blank. I think it's most fair.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `read` to skip parsing (and removing) escapes and quotes by using its `-r` ("raw") option. But, as everyone has said, *you do not want to do this*. Having escapes and/or quotes embedded in the values assigned to shell variables doesn't do anything useful, because the shell does not parse them when it expands variables. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1226417/bash-reports-file-does-not-exist-but-it-does) for an example of someone having trouble specifically because they had escapes embedded in the filenames they were trying to use.

Here's an example of doing this right:

```
$ cat t1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'click and drag your file here'
read -p " " FilepatH
echo 'You chose '"$FilepatH"
echo
echo "Trying to use the variable with double-quotes:"
ls -l "$FilepatH"

$ ./t1.sh
click and drag your file here
 /Users/gordon/weird\ chars\:\ \'\"\\\(\)\&\;.txt 
You chose /Users/gordon/weird chars: '"\()&;.txt

Trying to use the variable with double-quotes:
-rw-r--r--  1 gordon  staff  0 Jul 19 22:56 /Users/gordon/weird chars: '"\()&;.txt
```

And here's doing it wrong (with `read -r`):

```
$ cat t2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'click and drag your file here'
read -r -p " " FilepatH
echo 'You chose '"$FilepatH"
echo
echo "Trying to use the variable with double-quotes:"
ls -l "$FilepatH"
echo
echo "Trying to use the variable without double-quotes:"
ls -l $FilepatH

$ ./t2.sh 
click and drag your file here
 /Users/gordon/weird\ chars\:\ \'\"\\\(\)\&\;.txt 
You chose /Users/gordon/weird\ chars\:\ \'\"\\\(\)\&\;.txt

Trying to use the variable with double-quotes:
ls: /Users/gordon/weird\ chars\:\ \'\"\\\(\)\&\;.txt: No such file or directory

Trying to use the variable without double-quotes:
ls: /Users/gordon/weird\: No such file or directory
ls: \'\"\\\(\)\&\;.txt: No such file or directory
ls: chars\:\: No such file or directory
```

Note that with the variable in double-quotes, it tried to treat the escapes as literal parts of the filename. Without them, it split the file path into separate items based on spaces, and then *still* treated the escapes as literal parts of the filenames.